# Name of theorem for integrating positive function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

I'm working on an integral used to illustrate $\pi > \frac{22}{7}$ and I'm stuck on finding the name of a theorem for the following:

Let $f(x)$ be a continuous Real Valued function on the interval $[a,b]$ (where $a$, $b$ can be finite or infinite). If $f(x) \geq 0$ on $[a,b]$ then 
$$
\int_a^b f(x) \:dx \geq 0
$$

Does anyone know what the name of this theorem is?

Comment: Fundamental Theorem of Calculus? lol it isn't that I don't think, but it's quite similar.

Comment: There is no name for it. It is obvious from the definition of the integral so nobody thought  of giving it  a name.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy - I've learned to never trust someone who uses "It is obvious" as a mathematical argument.

Comment: Then unlearn it. In this case, it **is** obvious.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos - I prefer to rely on proofs.

Comment: I meant that it is obvious how to prove it. Since $f\geqslant0$, the lower sum of $f$ with respect to the partition $\{a,b\}$ of $[a,b]$ is non-negative. QED

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this helps (or if you really *need* a name for that theorem), but the property that $f \ge g$ on $[a,b]$ (where $a \le b$) implies $\int_a^b f(x) \, dx \ge \int_a^b g(x) \, dx$ is sometimes called **monotonicity** of the integral.

Comment: This is great as it is a more generalised form of what I posted (with $g(x) = 0$). 
Very much appreciate the post.

Comment: Well, its generalised like MVT is a generalised Rolles (they're equivalent)

Comment: @CalvinKhor - My apologies for not using the absolute correct terminology. Thank you for your post.

Comment: Sorry if I'm misinterpreting, but is my sarcasm detector picking up a false positive? I meant it earnestly. The fact that MVT is a generalised Rolles is not useless information

Comment: @CalvinKhor - Oh no, I greatly appreciate that correction. Thank you again for your enriching post.

Comment: Oh, in which case, you're very very welcome. God bless your soul

Answer (score 1):

A theorem stating exactly this property has (in all likelihood) no name since this is neither a deep result nor a property specific to integrals.

However, given an ordered real vector space $(V,\leq)$ and a functional (linear map) $F : V\to \mathbb R$ we say $F$ is [positive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_linear_functional) if $v\geq 0$ implies $f(v)\geq 0$ for all $v\in V$. Note, that we can define functionals of the form

$$\int_a^b : A\to \mathbb R, f\mapsto \int_a^b f(x)\,dx,$$

for any vector space $A$ of integrable functions $[a,b]\to \mathbb R$.

So it would be most reasonable to call this property *positivity of the integral*.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this theorem has a name. It is however a property named **positivity of the integral**.

Comment: Thank you for your post. I was unable to find anything with a quick google search. In saying that, this is not my area of expertise so I very well may not be using the correct search terms.